# JS to PHP error

Tags: javascript, php

I have some JS code which I want to convert to PHP code. I changed all the things that I know should, but it doesn't give the same result.

**The PHP code** I created from the JS code:

```
<?php
function hashCode($str){
    $hash = 0;

    if (strlen($str) == 0) return $hash;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
          $char = $str[$i];
          $hash = (($hash<<5) - $hash) + $char;
          $hash = $hash & $hash;
    }
    return $hash;
}
?>
```

When entering a string 
it returns 0 and that is not because of the if function.
**Original code:**

```
hashCode = function(str){
    var hash = 0;
    if (str.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Arend-Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, in the javascript, the char is the code of the caracter (`charCodeAt)`. So this will do the same. Use `ord($char)`

```
function hashCode($str) {
    $hash = 0;
    if (strlen($str) == 0) {
        return $hash;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $char = $str[$i];
        $hash = (($hash << 5) - $hash) + ord($char);
        $hash = $hash & $hash;
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

If string is ABCD, the output will be this, in both case:

```
65
2081
64578
2001986
2001986
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried with an simple word like "felien" and there came JS:-1278196699 and PHP:3016770597 so it doesn't work completely.